# ADO.NET Entity Data Model Wizard - Model Class file not getting created

Tags: ado.net-entity-data-model

Used the "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" Wizard.
Gave the corresponding connectivity and once the wizard completes, the .edmx file opens with the diagram containing my table structure.
But the Model Class file is not created.

How to overcome this error?
I even build the solution, also checked by using "Show All Files".Nothing works out.(using VS2010 SP1, EF6)

Comment: Just checking... Did you remember to check the tables you wanted in the wizard?

Comment: Do your tables contain a Primary Key?

Comment: Yes, I selected the tables in the wizard.

Comment: Yes, the table contains the PK

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 is old software. Any chance you can upgrade to Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4?

Comment: I deleted the entire project and tried again. It worked fine. (Still not sure what was the cause for this issue.)

Comment: With Visual Studio 2010, which EF version to use ?

Comment: I recall using EF 5.x with VS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted the project and tried again and then was able to find the model file.
This is not the correct answer but as it solved the issue, this might be an answer for this issue.

Comment: 9 out of 10  times, deleting the data model and re-adding it solved block issue. However, when using the latest EF 6.x, one doesn't need to do that very often anymore.